# I get an error with my PHP code updating one table

Tags: php, mysql

I get an error with my PHP code when updating the table `patient`. I cannot find the problem.

Here is my error:

> Verification Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

```
<?php
$edit = mysql_query("UPDATE `patient` SET `date`='$date', `fname`='$fname', `lname`='$lname', `birthday`='$dob', `address`='$address', `work`='$work', `civil`='$civil', `gender`='$sex', `btype`='$bloodtype', `height`='$hgt', `weight`='$wgt', `fallergy`='$fallergy', `mallergy`='$mallergy' WHERE `patientid`='$vara'");
$result = mysql_query($edit) or die("Verification Error: " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: $edit = mysql_query("UPDATE `patient` SET `date`='$date', `fname`='$fname', `lname`='$lname', `birthday`='$dob', `address`='$address', `work`='$work', `civil`='$civil', `gender`='$sex', `btype`='$bloodtype', `height`='$hgt', `weight`='$wgt', `fallergy`='$fallergy', `mallergy`='$mallergy' WHERE `patientid`='$vara'");
  $result = mysql_query($edit) or die("Verification Error: " . mysql_error());

Comment: use echo $edit; after your query in $edit .And copy paste the query string in Database, phpmyadmin. And tell us what is error.

Comment: Next time you create a question or answer, please put more effort into it. We should not have to clean up after you.

Comment: sorry . i dont know how to that way.

Comment: @EverythingRichardify , hi , I asked : use echo $edit; after your query in $edit .And copy paste the query string in Database, phpmyadmin. And tell us what is error.

Comment: when i echo $edit; it just display number 1. -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `mysql_query` twice; the second time you pass the result, of the first call, into it as an argument. That is not how `mysql_query` works. The SQL should just be a string:

```
$edit = "UPDATE `patient` SET `date`='$date', `fname` ...";
$result = mysql_query($edit) or die("Verification Error: " . mysql_error());
```

We cannot see the rest of your code, so we do not know if there are more problems, but this should fix the problem in your question.